# Is there a more clear way to write out multiple functions that are part of an object?

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
   $scope.modalReset = function () {
        gridService.modalReset($scope);
    }

    $scope.rowAction = function (action, row) {
        gridService.rowAction(action, $scope, row, 'Question');
    }

    $scope.submitItem = function (formData) {
        gridService.submitItem($scope, 'Question', formData);
    }
```

Is there a way that these function calls could be written more simply. I am not looking to combine them. There are all functions that are part of the scope object.

Comment: "More simply" is quite vague and difficult to answer without knowing a whole lot about the context this code is executing in

Comment: I'm not looking to combine. Just given the functionality which is here. Three functions all being a part of $scope.  Is there a different way to write the above. It looks clumsy to me. If the answer is "no" then I think that's quite okay.

Comment: I understand you don't want to combine them. I think what you're doing is fine. If you want to completely overwrite `$scope` (which I don't think you want to do because this is Angular code?) then you can assign an object to it containing your functions instead.

Comment: What do you mean by "combine them"? What part of it looks clumsy to you?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to encapsulate these tree functions then there are two methods that come to mind.

**Method 1: The `with` Statement** (Please don't use this method. It has [lots](http://www.barryvan.com.au/2009/05/avoid-javascripts-with-keyword/) of [problems](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with).)

```
with ($scope) {
    modalReset = function () {
        gridService.modalReset($scope);
    };

    rowAction = function (action, row) {
        gridService.rowAction(action, $scope, row, "Question");
    };

    submitItem = function (formData) {
        gridService.submitItem($scope, "Question", formData);
    };
}
```

**Method 2: Object Literals** (This is the recommended method.)

```
define($scope, {
    modalReset: function () {
        gridService.modalReset($scope);
    },
    rowAction: function (action, row) {
        gridService.rowAction(action, $scope, row, "Question");
    },
    submitItem = function (formData) {
        gridService.submitItem($scope, "Question", formData);
    }
});
```

This method requires a function called `define`:

```
function define(obj, props) {
    for (var key in props)
        if (props.hasOwnProperty(key))
            obj[key] = props[key];
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: The `with` statement doesn't work this way at all (unless the three properties have been defined before already)

Comment: @Bergi Lol. My bad. I never use `with` so I wouldn't know anyway. Will it work if I declared it using `var`?

Comment: No, `with` only introduces a new lookup scope. The *variableEnvironment* that is used for [variable/function] declarations stays the same

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, you can use `$.extend`:

```
$.extend($scope, {
    modalReset: function () {
        gridService.modalReset($scope);
    },
    rowAction: function (action, row) {
        gridService.rowAction(action, $scope, row, "Question");
    },
    submitItem = function (formData) {
        gridService.submitItem($scope, "Question", formData);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you're using AngularJS (`$scope`, etc.). In that case, use [`angular.extend()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.extend) like this:

```
angular.extend($scope, {
  modalReset: function () {
    ...
  },

  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way that these function calls could be written more simply

They're function definitions, not calls :-) There's not much similarity between their contents, so your current way is fine - if you don't like the triple assignment, you can use the `extend` functionality proposed in the other answers.

But if the `gridService` methods had a more uniform signature, like

```
$scope.modalReset = function () {
    gridService.modalReset($scope);
};
$scope.rowAction = function (action, row) {
    gridService.rowAction($scope, 'Question', action, row);
};
$scope.submitItem = function (formData) {
    gridService.submitItem($scope, 'Question', formData);
};
```

then you might shorten it to

```
["modalReset", "rowAction", "submitItem"].forEach(function(methodName) {
     $scope[methodName] = gridService[methodName].bind(gridService, $scope, "Question");
});
```